# Why am i getting an error saying "cannot open hello.docx"

Tags: cmd

So my code should inore uppercase or lowercase, search through hello.docx for the keyword "hello", the list that file. it gives my the error "cannot open hello.docx". Anyone know why that is?

This is my code I am typing into command prompt.

```
findstr /m /i "hello" hello.docx
```

Comment: Docx is a binary format - not a text file. You can’t use findstr with docx files.

Comment: I think you may not be in the correct directory. Try specifying the fully qualified path to the file. `C:\path\to\the\hello.docx`. The .docx is Microsoft''s attempt at an "open" file format and is in an XML-like format.

Answer (score 1):

A .DocX is a zip file so you need to unzip it to read the plain text (wrapped in the document.xml file.)

[image]

[image]

So your command needs to be as a minimum

```
tar -m -xf "hello.docx" & findstr /S /m /i /c:"hello" *
```

NOTES

- -m is required to stop tar screaming about modified dates
- -xf is for default extract ALL. So in this known format case you could target faster just the contents `word\document.xml` file
- You could extract to %temp% and just test find or findstr in the
  `%temp%\word\document.xml`
- If processing multiple files you could
  report the source name before the next overwrite of the
  %temp%\word\document.xml